# How to remove the white space around a chart in chart.js

Tags: typescript, canvas, chart.js, svelte

I have a chart inside a div element, as shown below, that has white space around it. How would I remove the white space there?
[inspected element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGZng.png)
[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xAcQ.png)

I've tried all the answers here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546993/chartjs-is-there-any-way-to-remove-blank-space-around-pie-charts#:~:text=According%20to%20the%20docs%20here,Hope%20this%20helps%20someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546993/chartjs-is-there-any-way-to-remove-blank-space-around-pie-charts#:%7E:text=According%20to%20the%20docs%20here,Hope%20this%20helps%20someone)! but none of them seem to work with the latest version of chartjs (I am on 4.2.1).

chart code:

```
import { Chart } from "chart.js/auto"
import { curvePlugin, textPlugin } from "./plugins"

type ChartGauge = typeof Chart

export interface Props {
  // may add more prop vals later
  value: number
}

export const addChart = (node: HTMLElement, params: Props): ChartGauge => {
  const text = textPlugin(params)
  const curve = curvePlugin()
  return new Chart(node, {
    type: "doughnut",
    data: {
      datasets: [
        {
          //label: params.caption,
          data: [params.value, 100 - params.value],
          backgroundColor: ["#056DFF", "#D9D9D9"],
          borderColor: ["rgba(255, 255, 255 ,1)"],
          borderWidth: 0,
        },
      ],
    },
    options: {
      rotation: -90,
      cutout: "85%",
      circumference: 180,
      radius: "50%",
      responsive: false
    },
    plugins: [text, curve],
  })
}
```

Display code:

```
  <div>
    <canvas
    id="chart"
    use:addChart={{value}}
    >
    </canvas>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please share the code, maybe also a REPL https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.58.0 and if this might be version related, the version number could be helpful

Comment: Edited my question with the code and version number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the radius to a higher value [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/0d844addaa7b41c9b3f491020410cc54?version=3.58.0)

```
options: {
    ...
    radius: "80%",
},
```